# Showing my own and then Unity's splashscreen

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, splash-screen

I am building a project for iOS with the newest version of Unity3D, v. 5.0.1p1 and as such it is fine.

The project is an old project first made in v.4. For some reason, since I upgraded Unity when opening the app on my device (iPhone 6) it first shows my own splash-screen but after a while it shows "Made with Unity" splash-screen just before the app is finished loading? I have tried everything in the build setting under splash-screen but nothing works?

I have Unity Pro.

[image]

Has anyone experienced the same problem and if yes... How do I solve this?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 3):

Go to Player Settings -> Splash Section - > Uncheck Show Unity Splash option

Comment: This is the correct answer. They seem to have changed this and auto checked this "feature".

Answer (score 0):

According to the EULA: http://unity3d.com/legal/eula

> Although Unity Personal has most of the features and functionality
>   that Unity Pro has, Unity Personal: (a) includes certain features that
>   cannot be disabled when your application is launched, including a
>   Unity branded startup screen and certain analytics data collection;

Upgrade to the Pro version if you want to remove the Unity splash screen.

Comment: OK, that's very weird then.

Comment: Yes I know?!? Hoping someone can explain whats wrong here. It also is an issue on projects as well!? First my own splash-screen followed by the Unity splash-screen?

Comment: I've never come across this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this changed in Unity 5, see below from the unity site, but it seems you must purchase IOS and Android Pro to remove splash screens from the respective platforms.

> For Unity 5 Professional Edition
>
> Unity 5 Professional customers who earned/received more than $100,000 in revenue/funding in the previous fiscal year must purchase iOS Pro and/or Android Pro deployment add-ons to deploy to these platforms. **The iOS and Android Pro add-ons enable deployment without the Personal Edition splash screen.**
>
> Unity 5 Professional customers who earned/received less than $100,000 in revenue/funding in the previous fiscal year can deploy with included iOS and Android support with the Personal Edition splash screen.

(From: http://unity3d.com/get-unity and click the ? next to "All Platforms")